# Removing IPN From Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to change my IPN listener from sandbox mode to live, and it isn't working for me. It says to leave the $paypalmode variable blank for live more, and it isn't working. Any solutions?
Code:

```
    <?php
       //Change these with your information
    $paypalmode = 'sandbox'; //Sandbox for testing or empty ''
    $dbusername     = 'username'; //db username
    $dbpassword     = 'password'; //db password
    $dbhost     = 'localhost'; //db host
    $dbname     = 'db_name'; //db name

if($_POST)
{
        if($paypalmode=='sandbox')
        {
            $paypalmode     =   '.sandbox';
        }
        $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www'.$paypalmode.'.sandbox.paypal.com'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $payerid = $_POST['payer_id'];
            $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
            $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
            $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
            $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $itemname = $_POST['item_name1'];
            $cost = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
            $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
            if (!$conn)
            {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

            // insert in our IPN record table
            $query = "INSERT INTO ibn_table
            (itransaction_id,itemname, cost, ipayerid,iname,iemail,itransaction_date, ipaymentstatus,ieverything_else)
            VALUES
            ('$transaction_id', '$itemname', '$cost','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate', '$paymentstatus','$otherstuff')";

            if(!mysql_query($query))
            {
                //mysql error..!
            }
            mysql_close($conn);

        }
}
?>
```

I was simulating an IPN on PayPal's developer pages, and in sandbox mode, this code works smoothly. But live mode gives me issues. Not necessarily errors, because an error_log.txt file will be developed, but my tables is not updating.

Comment: In this code it's still using sandbox for the paypalmode..??

Comment: Yeah firstly you will need to set $paypalmode to empty string (currently the code shows otherwise). Secondly, IPN simulator will only send IPN in sandbox mode, so you will need to run an actual live transaction to get live IPN

Comment: Thanks guys! I had the PayPal mode in an empty string but i sent an IPN simulator. I'll give it a try with a real transaction.